# try to make black image but getting error for np.unit8

Tags: python, numpy

I have just started to learn OpenCV. trying to make a black window by the code:

```
img=np.zeros((512,512,3),np.unit8)
```

but get the error:

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'unit8'
```

Answer (score 4):

numpy has no datatype such as `unit8`.

it must be `uint8`.

have a look at [numpy docs datatypes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)